# Simultaneous remote connections

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control, remote, remote-x-session

Is there any package for Ubuntu which allows me to connect to remote computer without disturbing or terminating others who have already connected to that server or who are accessing the computer directly?.

I remember I did this in `Windows Server 2003` installing `Terminal Server` when I was doing my course which allowed multiple clients to connect to the server simultaneously with no disturbance to clients and even direct access to server.

Is there any package like this for Ubuntu desktops?

Comment: Any good tool for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NOMACHINE](http://www.nomachine.com/) could be the best choice as it has a feature which doesn't reveal what a remote user is doing on and won't disturb other users who have already connected to it. In ubuntu nomachine is packaged as [FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX)

Thanks!

Comment: NOMACHINE works great but restricted to only one session https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00703 "NoMachine (free) allows one connection. Hence it is for individual use."

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Ubuntu by default support VNC. Try using Terminal Server or Remote Desktop Viewer.

Comment: Can two user connect at a time and take the control

Answer (score 1):

This thing i have checked by installing on two ubuntu pcs and confirmed working...

[ubuntu 14.10 multiple Simultaneous independent remote (desktop like ) connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581979/ubuntu-14-10-multiple-simultaneous-independent-remote-desktop-like-connection/603448#603448)

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get install rdesktop

This will work natively with windows as it uses the same protocols. This is to connect from Linux to a windows server.

If you want to connect to the Linux server from other computers using vnc would be worth investigating.

> sudo apt-get install vnc4server

Comment: VNC is dam slow and other can easily look and take control

Comment: FreeNX is also a good product to check out. Not included in the repositories, but could be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you need no UI and terminal is just enough for you use SSH (Secure Shell) to connect remotely

```
ssh remote_username@remote_host
```

you can even transfer files with SCP (Secure Copy)

```
scp your_username@remotehost:filename.ext /some/local/directory
```