# Problem with following directions for multi-user VNC server setup

Tags: server, vnc

While following the steps described at this answered question ([ubuntu 14.10 multiple Simultaneous independent remote (desktop like ) connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581979/ubuntu-14-10-multiple-simultaneous-independent-remote-desktop-like-connection/948072#948072)), I am unable to complete Step 8 it seems -

sudo `update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99`

I get this message:

```
adam@server:/etc/init.d$ sudo `update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99`
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 [...omitted for privacy]
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...
```

When I reboot, the VNC server is not running. 
Any thoughts? I followed all of the other instructions verbatim.

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? The init system has changed since that answer was posted, I'm not sure that `update-rc.d` is appropriate now. Regardless, the command probably should not have backticks as shown there.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS. I didn't realize the init system has changed.